# Javascript: setAttribute() v.s. element.attribute = value to set "name" attribute

Tags: javascript, setattribute, getelementsbyname

So I'm learning to manipulate the DOM and I noticed one interesting thing:

Let's say I want to set the `name` attribute of an element by using the "." dot notation:

```
element.name = "someName";
console.log(document.getElementsByName("someName")[0]); // returns "undefined"??
```

However if I use the `document.setAttribute()` method, it works fine:

```
element.setAttribute("name", "someName");
console.log(document.getElementsByName("someName")[0]); // returns the element like it should.
```

Not sure why the dot notation method doesn't work in the first case.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Generally try to avoid using `getElementsByName`

Comment: Why should one avoid using getElementsByName?

Comment: Attributes ARE accessible using dot notation if that is how you wish to access them. If you wish to access attributes using dot notation you need to refer to obj.attributes.attributeName to retrieve the attribute and obj.attributes.attributeName.value to manipulate its value. It's long winded when compared with setAttribute or getAttribute. and not recommended as a solution, but regardless of that, a full answer to your question "Why doesn't dot notation work in the first case" - has to include "it does. You were just looking in the wrong place for the attributes and their values."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My guess (because you didn't specify the element type) is the element normally does not have a `name` attribute, so setting the DOM property like that won't work.

For example, setting the `name` property on an `input` element will work. Setting it on a `div` will not.

It will work, however, with `setAttribute()`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQ2Zp/).

Comment: Sir when I set some html element attribute as "undefined" , it does not work, and it continues to take its previous values. Can you tell me why is so ?

Comment: @SurajJain Probably because the API doesn't allow the attribute to be `undefined`.

Comment: Almost a year passed .

Answer (score 9):

To extend the answers provided by some of the others ...

The attribute 'name' is only considered valid DOM for a few specific objects. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name those objects are:

```
 <a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, 
 <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>
```

For these objects you can set, get and change the name attribute using `object.name` BUT FOR ANY OTHER DOM OBJECT the attribute 'name' is a custom attribute and must be created using `SetAttribute()` or by adding it to the HTML declaration. Once it is created, you can acces it using `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` or you can refer to its value directly using `object.attributes.name.value` take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/radiotrib/yat72/1/ for an example. BTW - the alert box on load is intentional - check the code to see why ...

Answer (score 3):

(Attempting to explain part of the above post a better, separately, since it is already went into -ve rating, and belief in that post will be less. Help improve this further if not better.)

*** The `property`

When you use, element.name, you are accessing an existing `property` named "name" or setting its value.

```
Example 1:
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1"); 
div1.textContent = "2";
```

*** The `attribute`

but, while using, `element.setAttribute('name','someName')`, you are actually setting the `attribute` named 'name'.
This attribute can be an existing property OR a custom one we want:

```
Example 2:
var h1 = document.getElementById("H1"); 
h1.setAttribute("class", "democlass");

Example 3:
var d = document.getElementById("d1"); 
d.setAttribute("name1", "value1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script>
function test($count) {
document.getElementById("test1").setAttribute("name","file-upload_" + $count);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>some content</p>
<input id="test1" type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
<p>some other content</p>
<script>test(1);</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use, element.name, you are accessing the property/creating a property named "name" and setting its value.

Answer (score 0):

when you use, element.name, you are accessing the property/creating a property named "name" and setting its value.

but,

while using, element.setAttribute('name','someName'), you are actually setting the attribute 'name'.

IE8 and below treats the property and attribute as same, the bug has been fixed in IE9 and above.
Safari, FireFox, Chrome treat property and attribute differently.

However, you can always create a new property of your choice if you wish to do so.

Comment: partial answer ... limited and does not explain the reasoning behind the problem