# How to assign datalist to input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off">

<datalist id="seek_list">
<option value="Value1">
<option value="Value2">
</datalist>
```

and this Javascript:

```
$('input[name=city]').on('keyup', function()
{
    if (this.value.length > 1)
    {
        this.list = 'seek_list';
    }
    else
    {
        this.list = ''; 
    }
});
```

I want the autocomplete to work after user types 2 or more chars in the input field, but this doesn't work. The datalist is not assigned.
I also tried this approach but with no luck:

```
<input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off" list="seek_list">

<datalist>
<option value="Value1">
<option value="Value2">
</datalist>

$('input[name=city]').on('keyup', function()
{
    if (this.value.length > 1)
    {
        $('datalist')[0].id = "seek_list";
    }
    else
    {
        $('datalist')[0].id = "";
    }
});
```

The only thing that worked was an empty datalist with this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off" list="seek_list">

<datalist id="seek_list">
</datalist>
```

and appending options to the datalist with Javascript, but that was slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set attribute of the element use [`.attr(attributeName, value)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) and [`.removeAttr(attributeName)`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$('input[name=city]').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        $(this).attr('list', 'seek_list');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('list')
    }
});
```

Comment: But what is the difference between $(this).attr('list') and this.list? NVM found out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426461/javascript-setattribute-v-s-element-attribute-value-to-set-name-attribut

Comment: @Tom, `this.list` means you are fetching the property of `this` object. and input doesn't have a `list` property