# document.createElement with name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to specify `name=""` when using `document.createElement` but isn't working.

Here is the code =>

```js
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.className = "hello-there";
element.innerText = "It works";
element.name = "hello-there-name";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(element);
console.log(document.querySelector("p").getAttribute("name"));
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

How can I fix that without using `id`? Thanks

Comment: you can set attribute by `someElement.setAttribute("name", "hello-there-name");`

Comment: There are no better way to set name without setAttribute? This is very ugly since I'm using className and innerText directly.

Comment: `<p>` elements don't have a name. Form elements do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` don't have `name` attributes. Try `data-name` instead:

```js
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.className = "hello-there";
element.innerText = "It works";
element.dataset.name = "hello-there-name";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(element);
console.log(document.querySelector("p"));
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `setAttribute`:

```js
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.className = "hello-there";
element.innerText = "It works";
element.setAttribute("name", "hello-there-name");
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(element);
console.log(document.querySelector("p").getAttribute("name"));
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. There are no better way to set name without setAttribute? This is very ugly since I'm using className and innerText directly. (I didnt downvote you)

Comment: @DavelonSahz Nope, this is the only way (there are other ways but they're longer and pointless) that you should use. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426461/javascript-setattribute-v-s-element-attribute-value-to-set-name-attribut) for why.